# I have a problem respect to CONSTRUCT of SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have a problem with respect to `CONSTRUCT` of SPARQL. The `CONSTRUCT` doesn't return the same number of the instance that a `SELECT`. The `WHERE` is the same in both of the cases.

- for example, for this query returns the 800 people.

```sql
select distinct ?p1
where {
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/gender> ?gender.
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosis> ?d1.
?d1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosisAge> ?age.
... ...                 ...
... ...                 ...
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/survivalMonths> ?survivalMonths.

FILTER( (xsd:integer(?age) > "20"^^xsd:integer) && (xsd:integer(?age) < "90"^^xsd:integer)).
}
```

- but for this `CONSTRUCT`, which has the same `WHERE` sentence that the `SELECT` does not return the same number of people. Returns 500 people.

```sql
construct { 

?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/gender> ?gender.
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosis> ?d1.
?d1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosisAge> ?age.
... ...                 ...
... ...                 ...
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/survivalMonths> ?survivalMonths.

}
where {
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/gender> ?gender.
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosis> ?d1.
?d1 <http://project.eu/vocab/hasDiagnosisAge> ?age.
... ...                 ...
... ...                 ...
?p1 <http://project.eu/vocab/survivalMonths> ?survivalMonths.

FILTER( (xsd:integer(?age) > "20"^^xsd:integer) && (xsd:integer(?age) < "90"^^xsd:integer)).
}
```

but if I change the filter from 20 to 70 age in both queries then I get the same results. 400 person.

Comment: which SPARQL endpoint? there might be a limit of triples that can be returned, thus, you might need pagination aka `limit x offset x*page_number order by ...`

Comment: It's best to always provide the engine name and version, and if publicly accessible, a link to the endpoint in question. I'm guessing that's a Virtuoso-served endpoint, and you're running into either or both of the [Anytime Query feature](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtTipsAndTricksAnytimeSPARQLQuery) and a result set size limit (`maxrows` INI file setting).